# Server.Transfer losing post data

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-6, server.transfer, postdata

I am having trouble with a web application that is losing post data during Server.Transfer, but only in our production environment.

The form is posted by the user and in turn Server.Transfer occurs, after which the postdata is used to generate the response. All works well in our dev and staging environments but in the live environment the post data is being lost.

The data is only lost when a Server.Transfer occurs - other forms' post data is being accepted fine.

The application is ASP.NET 4.0, and the web server is IIS6. As far as I am aware the configuration is the same, and the server is fully patched with Windows and .NET Framework updates.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `Web Farm` enabled in production?

Comment: When `EnableViewStateMac` is True, I think Server.Transfer won't preserve posted form data. Try setting it to false, though [it's not recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: `Web Farm` is not enabled. I have tried altering `EnableViewStateMac` settings, but it does not seem to have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never got to the bottom of this problem, but I've worked around it for now.